# Deprecated cucumber option annotations

Tags: class

```
package Runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.java.en.*;

@RunWith(CucumberOptions.class)

@CucumberOptions(features="resources/feature", glue="step")
public class Runner 
{
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question. What are you trying to achieve? What is the problem?

Comment: What does the Javadoc of the deprecated annotation tell you?